# Linux command to tell if the machine is physical or virtual

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, physical-environment

How can we check whether the machine is a physical or virtual one in Linux?

Which command can be used?

Comment: Was there a reason you tagged this question `redhat-enterprise-linux`? Or is the `linux` tag more appropriate?  Please edit your tags as necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've got systemd installed, it comes with `systemd-detect-virt`.

```
me@real-machine:~$ systemd-detect-virt 
none

me@vm:~$ systemd-detect-virt 
qemu
```

Can detect many different types of virtualization and containers, too.

If don't have systemd, there is also [`virt-what`](https://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) which has a package at least on Debian (and considering where it comes from, unsurprisingly for RedHat too).

See also [“Easy way to determine virtualization technology” on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89714/977) for a bunch more approaches.

Answer (score 10):

Using `lshw` will give you system information:

1. Run the command: `sudo apt-get install lshw`

   - NOTE: This command may vary depending on the Linux distribution.
2. Run the command: `sudo lshw -class system`
3. This will show information about the system. For example, if the machine is a Dell or HP, that will be the **product**. In the case of a virtual machine, the product will be the name of the emulator.

Comment: You can also do something equivalent with dmidecode

Answer (score 0):

Similar question in serverfault:

[VMware Linux Server — how can you tell if you are a vm or real hardware?](https://serverfault.com/questions/65718/vmware-linux-server-how-can-you-tell-if-you-are-a-vm-or-real-hardware)

And my answer :-)

[hostnamectl status](https://serverfault.com/a/949673/376916)